# Google Translate returns weird string?

Tags: php, google-translate

So I am trying to get a string back from google but translated as you can see

```php
function Translate($fromLang,$toLang,$text){
        $texts = file_get_contents(
        "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl="
        . $fromLang .
        "&tl=" . 
        $toLang . "&dt=t&q=" . $text);

        return $texts;
    }
```

But this returns an ugly string like this if the parameters are set to

```php
Print(Translate("en","es","Hello"));
```

`[[["Hola","Hello",null,null,1]],null,"en"]`

According to the "scattered" and poor documentation on personal use without paying the enterprise fees this should work

Comment: yea im not sure what looks like that is it an array i think i saw somewhere that it was json i just dont know what i need to be doing with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then return the third level of the array.

```
function Translate($fromLang,$toLang,$text){
    $texts = file_get_contents("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" . $fromLang . "&tl=" .  $toLang . "&dt=t&q=" . $text);
    $array = json_decode($texts, TRUE);
    return $array[0][0][0];
}
```

The returned JSON is two levels in, and the translated value is the first value of that. So you need `[0][0]` to get to the right level, and then `[0]` to get the value.

If you are unsure what to access you can always use `print_r` in the `Translate` function on the `$array` value to see what it contains.

Comment: mainly $array[0][0][0]

Comment: perhaps add that to your answer for future visitors :)